# is there any way to make the webform components labels translatable?

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

Just wondering how to make the webform components labels translatable. 
I found this post with a link to a sandbox project but I don't where to download the module: [Make Webform multilingual (i18n) aware through contributed modules](http://drupal.org/node/245424)

I also find this function to just make what I need but it doesn't work, maybe with a few change it will work: Source: [work around](http://wunderkraut.com/en/blog/quick-and-dirty-translation-field-labels-webforms)

```
function module_name_form_webform_client_form_xx_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  foreach (element_children($form['submitted']) as $element) { 
    // Pass each webform component title through the t() function. 
    $form['submitted'][$element]['#title'] = t($form['submitted'][$element]['#title']); 
  } 
}
```

The function provided  by ***@lenni*** does the job but I get these error messages.

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given en
>   drupal_validate_utf8() (línea 1600
>   de/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tonisacristan.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion en filter_xss() (línea 1366 de
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tonisacristan.com/includes/common.inc).
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion en format_string() (línea 1552 de
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tonisacristan.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).

The source of the problem is a Markup component. This function is working fine.

```
function webform_extras_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type == 'webform' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // translate the webform component labels
    foreach(element_children($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted']) as $key){
      //to skip Markup components
      if($key != 'my_markup_component'){
        $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title'] = t($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar (a litte bit more generic) solution but still not a clean one:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type == 'webform' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // translate the webform component labels
    foreach(element_children($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted']) as $key){
      $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title'] = t($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does the job, but I get some error messages. I added these message at the bottom of my question. Can you help with this?

Comment: Are you sure the errors are related to this workaround?

Comment: Yes, the source of the problem is a Markup component. I added 1 more line to your function. See it at bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

And if you actually want to translate your markup fields as well, which is often the case:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {  

  if ($node->type == 'webform') {
    // translate the webform component labels
    foreach(element_children($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted']) as $key){
      if($key != 'your_markup_component' && $key != 'your_markup_component_2'){
        $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title'] = t($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#title']);
      }
      else {
        $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#value'] = t($node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted'][$key]['#value']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```